How can i preselect all the values as default in lightning dual list box
Hello i have a similaire question i'm new with js
    <lightning-dual-listbox
      name="SIRET"
      id="listAtt"
      label="Choisir les piéces jointes"
      source-label="Disponible"
      selected-label="Selectionné"
      field-level-help="Choisir les Etablissements que vous souhaitez rattacher à cette Souscription"
      options={attachs}
      value={selectedAttachs}
    >

this is how i get attachs:
 this.attachs = data.attachments.map((item) => ({
          label: item.ContentDocument.Title,
          value: item.Id
        }));

i want the list to be in preselection so
this.selectedAttachs = this.attachs.map((attachment) => attachment.value);
but it does not work

What do you mean it doesn’t work? Do you get an error? What is the state of selectedAttachs ? Please edit your question to include more information about where you’re stuck

Make sure that this.selectedAttachs is set after this.attachs is populated with the mapped values.
Example JS:
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class DualListBoxExample extends LightningElement {
        @track attachs = [];
        @track selectedAttachs = [];

        connectedCallback() {
                this.fetchAttachments();
        }

        fetchAttachments() {
                // Simulate data fetching
                const data = {
                        attachments: [
                                { ContentDocument: { Title: 'Document 1' }, Id: '1' },
                                { ContentDocument: { Title: 'Document 2' }, Id: '2' },
                                { ContentDocument: { Title: 'Document 3' }, Id: '3' }
                        ]
                };

                // Map the attachments to the format required by the dual listbox
                this.attachs = data.attachments.map((item) => ({
                        label: item.ContentDocument.Title,
                        value: item.Id
                }));

                this.selectedAttachs = this.attachs.map((attachment) => attachment.value);
        }
}


HTML:
<template>
        <lightning-dual-listbox
                name="SIRET"
                id="listAtt"
                label="Choisir les piéces jointes"
                source-label="Disponible"
                selected-label="Selectionné"
                field-level-help="Choisir les Etablissements que vous souhaitez rattacher à cette Souscription"
                options={attachs}
                value={selectedAttachs}>
        </lightning-dual-listbox>
</template>

